# MacOS Language and Country Settings

Tags: internationalization, language

I switched to Mac recently. So I have this question:

I am in Germany, however, neither I speak nor read any German. Is it possible to set the Mac language to English and the country to Germany so that I can use the German App Store. (sorry if I sound naive, I have never used one before). If yes, how?

**Edit:** I want to use the German version of the App Store because I don't have a credit card (I am a student). I need to buy a few apps for my education.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization on OS X and the App Store you are using are two different things.

- Localization is done on User Account level, meaning you can define the language, the date format etc. individually for each user on your Mac
- The App Store is tied to the Apple ID used, so the Store you use is the one the Apple ID is connected with. You can't switch stores within one ID but it's possible (even if it's a bit cumbersome in practice) to have several IDs for different stores.